# Set Visibility of a control with custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<TextBlock.Visibility>
    <mat:MatcherConverter>
        <mat:Matcher MatchVisibility="Visible" DismatchVisibility="Collapsed">
            <mat:Matcher Value1="{Binding Boolean1}" Value2="True" ComparisonOperator="AND"/>
            <mat:Matcher Value1="{Binding Boolean2}" Value2="True" ComparisonOperator="AND"/>
        </mat:Matcher>
    </mat:MatcherConverter>
</TextBlock.Visibility>
```

What do you think about a class, that has MarkupExtension as baseclass?
in this case it would be the MatcherConverter. This class would go throug all matchers recursively and the result is a boolean.

Comment: Could you rephrase what your goal is?  What you said makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: This is extremely vague. What exactly is the problem? What have you tried and how did it not work out/match your expectations?

Comment: I dont know, how to convert <mat:Matcher/> to Visibility. Is a reasonable way to to this with MarkupExtension, then i could convert it in the ProvideValue Method.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve Hierarchical data representation (like nested tree view)? Web is full of examples for how to represent hierarchy data in WPF ... http://www.dev102.blogspot.com/2007/12/how-to-use-hierarchical-datatemplate-in.html

Answer (score 0):

You could make a property `TheBooleanResult` in `Matcher` than returns the boolean result you want to evaluate (on `Children` and `Value1`, `Value2`,...). Then make an `IValueConverter` that takes a `Matcher` and gets `TheBooleanResult` and returns the visibility you want.

```
public class MatcherConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Matcher m = (Matcher)value;
        return m.TheBooleanResult ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: @kusi581 I saw your comment on the question. You may place the `Matcher` in the usercontrols resources (perhaps as an `ObjectDataProvider`). Then bind the textbox's visibility property to that resource. [Example with ObjectDataProvider](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=22)

Comment: lets say i want the visibility based on 2 different conditions (example: user permission, global permission). Now i add a matcher to the visibility with 2 other matchers as children. The ComparisionOperator of the root matcher is AND, when both child-matchers are true, then its Visible, else collapsed. The Value1 of the children are binded to a Property on the model. So the combination of the matchers is always different

Comment: You could place it in the textbox's resources, but you seem to be looking for something else..